# Error: error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use `Xamarin.Forms` in order to develop cross platform application but I have an issue. I use `VS2015 Enterprise`. There is a problem when I simulate my application on iPhone Simulator. I selected "Configuration" mode as Debug and "Platform" mode as iPhone Simulator. In Windows side I use `Xamarin.iOS 11.2` and it's also the same for Mac side. And I can connect Windows to Mac successfully. I use `XCode 9.2`.

When I run my application, the output is:

> Launch failed. The app 'ADF.XPF.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone
>   5s iOS 11.2'. Error: error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator:
>   Could not find file
>   "/Users/yazilim/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ADF.XPF.iOS/3d07b519b07c870401ed8b5058cf1d91/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/trgovegmmobil.app/trgovegmmobil"

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752415/error-error-mt-failed-to-launch-the-simulator-mt0069-the-app-directory-doesn (even though it's not the same mtouch error). Your question came first though (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is reported if mtouch failed to launch the simulator. This can happen sometimes because there is already a stale or dead simulator process running.

The following command issued on the Unix command line can be used to kill stuck simulator processes:

```
$ launchctl list|grep UIKitApplication|awk '{print $3}'|xargs launchctl remove
```

Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt1008-failed-to-launch-the-simulator).

Comment: xia-MSFT I have the same issue on VS2019 and added the code in Unix Command of the MAC, but still getting the same issue. On the Mac I could see two Simulators are runnning.
Error Log

System.Exception: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not find file "/Users/userName/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/projectName.iOS/f5727f6bbdd6a791c1a56d7c269a65ff/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/projectName.iOS.app/projectName.iOS at Xamarin.Simulator.Core.Protocol.SimulatorClient.<InstallAndLaunchRemoteAppAsync>d__26.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\1703\s\Xamarin.Simulator.Core\Protocol\SimulatorClient.cs

Comment: Removing CFBundleExecutable from info.plist worked in MAUI