# Error: error MT: Failed to launch the simulator. MT0069: The app directory doesn't exist

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use in order to develop cross platform application in xamarin forms but I have an issue. I use vs 2015 enterprise. There is a problem, when I simulate my application on iphoneSimulator. I selected "Configuration" mode as Debug and "Platform" mode as IphoneSimulator. In Windows side I use Xamarin.ios 11.2 and macbook side is same xamarin.ios sdk too. And I can connect windows to macbook successfully. I use xcode version 9.2.

When I run my application,

Launch failed. The app 'ADF.XPF.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 5s iOS 11.2'. Error: error MT0069: The app directory '/Users/yazilim/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ADF.XPF.iOS/3d07b519b07c870401ed8b5058cf1d91/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/trgovegmmobil.app' does not exist.

Can you help me about it ?

Comment: Hi, that sounds like an issue with the Xamarin Visual Studio Extension build host to me. Sounds like the app wasn't build properly, maybe due to project options or a bug.

Would you mind reporting a new issue with Visual Studio 2017 directly within the IDE. Simply use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to file your issue.

Please add as much information as you can, test case, build logs, application output and version informations.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also struggling with this issue. I have VS 2019 Professional, Mac Catalina, XCode 11.1, Xamarin iOS and Mac SDK 13.4.0.2

Comment: After hours of research I managed to fix the issue: besides removing bin and obj I had to remove packages.

Comment: But I got it back and this time removing 'packages' folder does not help.

Comment: @DmitryMerkis did you work out a solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also met this before.

1.Delete the app in simulator

2.Delete `bin`,`obj` folder

3.Run again

This should solve the problem.

Comment: what do you mean when you say delete the app in simulator. would you be able to help me with the steps to delete the app in simulator?

Comment: @kiflay Click home button to enter homepage on simulator , find your application icon , delete it .

Comment: This does not fix the problem

Comment: This doesn't fix anything for me - the app is not even on the simulator in the first place - this happened since the first time I ever tried to debug on a simulator - did anyone try anything else that worked? @SergioAMG

Comment: I managed to fix this in the end by recloning my entire repository @SergioAMG

Comment: Removig CFBundleExecutable key worked from info.plist

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpful for somebody.

**I had the same problem.**

[image]

The message says that some folder of the path does not exists, so in my case i went to the MAC and i realized than the folder **mtbs** was not created.

[image]

**Solution**

***Create the missing folder***

[image]

After that clean, rebuild and launch the application again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30598199)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. I took a slightly more radical reproach, and re-cloned my entire GitHub repository on my windows machine. I didn't change anything on the mac, and it worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, nothing helped until I manually added the Xamarin.Build.Download package version 0.10.0

YourApp.iOS.csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include = "Xamarin.Build.Download" Version = "0.10.0" />
```